# extract text from xml using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file which is a part of a metadata (I extracted just one part of it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv http://schemas.opengis.net/iso/19139/20060504/srv/srv.xsd">
        <gmd:pointOfContact>
                    <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
                       <gmd:individualName xsi:type="gmd:PT_FreeText_PropertyType">
                          <gco:CharacterString>Freddie Mercury</gco:CharacterString>
                          <gmd:PT_FreeText>
                             <gmd:textGroup>
                                <gmd:LocalisedCharacterString locale="#ITA">Pippo</gmd:LocalisedCharacterString>
                             </gmd:textGroup>
                          </gmd:PT_FreeText>
                       </gmd:individualName>
                       <gmd:organisationName xsi:type="gmd:PT_FreeText_PropertyType">
                          <gco:CharacterString>The Queen</gco:CharacterString>
                          <gmd:PT_FreeText>
                             <gmd:textGroup>
                                <gmd:LocalisedCharacterString locale="#ITA">Music Institute</gmd:LocalisedCharacterString>
                             </gmd:textGroup>                         
                          </gmd:PT_FreeText>
                       </gmd:organisationName>
                       <gmd:positionName xsi:type="gmd:PT_FreeText_PropertyType">
                          <gco:CharacterString>Singer</gco:CharacterString>                              
                       </gmd:positionName>
                       <gmd:contactInfo>
                          <gmd:CI_Contact>
                             <gmd:phone>
                                <gmd:CI_Telephone>
                                   <gmd:voice>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>123456789</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:voice>
                                   <gmd:facsimile>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>123456789</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:facsimile>
                                </gmd:CI_Telephone>
                             </gmd:phone>
                             <gmd:address>
                                <gmd:CI_Address>                                  
                                   <gmd:city>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>Zanzibar</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:city>                                   
                                   <gmd:postalCode>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>00001</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:postalCode>
                                   <gmd:country>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>India</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:country>
                                   <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                                      <gco:CharacterString>info@test.org</gco:CharacterString>
                                   </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                                </gmd:CI_Address>
                             </gmd:address>
                             <gmd:transferOptions>
                <gmd:MD_DigitalTransferOptions>
                   <gmd:onLine>
                      <gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
                         <gmd:linkage>
                            <gmd:URL>http://www.google.it</gmd:URL>
                         </gmd:linkage>  
                      </gmd:CI_OnlineResource>
                   </gmd:onLine>               
                </gmd:MD_DigitalTransferOptions>
             </gmd:transferOptions>
                         </gmd:CI_Contact>
                       </gmd:contactInfo>
                       <gmd:role>
                          <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeListValue="pointOfContact" codeList="http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/ISO_19139_Schemas/resources/Codelist/ML_gmxCodelists.xml#CI_RoleCode"/>
                       </gmd:role>
        </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
        </gmd:pointOfContact>
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

I would like to extract only two information from this file: 
1. the text Freddie Mercury (gco:CharacterString)

2. the url http://www.google.it (gmd:URL)

I started trying using the following XSLT transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" gco:isoType="gmd:MD_Metadata"> 

    <xsl:template match="//gmd:pointOfContact">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gco:CharacterString" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="gco:CharacterString">
        <xsl:text>name=</xsl:text>          
    </xsl:template>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it is not working.

Could you please help me in this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to only output the text or create a new xml doc, but this stylesheet picks up the elements you want, I think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0"
xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" 
xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">

<!-- create new root element -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity templates walks tree and suppresses nodes with no template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>    
</xsl:template>

<!-- output only on nodes we select -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="output">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="output"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

<!-- match our two nodes and wrap in match tag. -->
<xsl:template match="gco:CharacterString[ancestor::gmd:individualName] | gmd:URL">
    <match>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="output"/>
    </match>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this creates the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"     xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"     xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">
<match>Freddie Mercury</match>
<match>http://www.google.it</match>
</root>
```

If you just wanted a text output you could specify that in your `xsl:method`. Also your description said you only wanted to output Freddy Mercury; the `gmd:individualName` was unique in this case, but not sure what kind of tagging variations there are on the set of files you would want to use this for.

This file only contained one `gmd:URL` tag, again not sure what kind of variation might exist, but this gets the output as per your question

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I would like to have a simple text file containing the two information "name,url" for example. 
I had to indicate the two tags because there are more than one in the entire metadata I have and I would like to be able to one I need.

Comment: then remove the 'match' tag in the template, and remove the root tag template, in the template where you want the output add <xsl:text>name: </xsl:text> followed by the apply-templates tag. Add <xsl:output method="text"/>

Comment: Thanks for this further suggestion. But could you please explain me better what do you mean when you wrote " in the template where you want the output add <xsl:text>name: </xsl:text> followed by the apply-templates tag"
because I tried but I'm doing some mistakes because it does not work